# Display csv endpoints instead of json

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Am making an nodejs express app for the endpoints i want to display the data in csv format instead of json format is this possible if so how could i go about implementing something like this

this is the code for one of the routes am using on my application :

```
const scraper = require("../scraper");
router.get("/:allegro", (req, res) => {
  scraper.process(req.param.allegro).then((list) => {
    res.json(list);
  });
});
```

note : scraper is the one responsible for giving the list of json data

```
here is a sample of the json data that needs to be displayed in csv format : 
 {
        "_id": "5edfd1de63b4c61b8c51ad71",
        "name": "Ford Focus 2.0 benzyna 145KM, krajowy,2 właściciel",
        "url": "https://allegro.pl/ogloszenie/ford-focus-2-0-benzyna-145km-krajowy-2-wlasciciel-9334876124",
        "price": "11700.00",
        "Stan": "Używany",
        "Przebieg": "212000 km",
        "Pochodzenie": "krajowe",
        "__v": 0
    },
```

Comment: In what format is `list`?

Comment: What does your response body (JSON) look like? Can you give us sample data to work from?

Comment: I'm going to recommend using a package like [`csv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv) from NPM... because, why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: @NicholasCarey i updated my question with a json sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a response body that looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    _id: "5edfd1de63b4c61b8c51ad71",
    name: "Ford Focus 2.0 benzyna 145KM, krajowy,2 właściciel",
    url: "https://allegro.pl/ogloszenie/ford-focus-2-0-benzyna-145km-krajowy-2-wlasciciel-9334876124",
    price: "11700.00",
    Stan: "Używany",
    Przebieg: "212000 km",
    Pochodzenie: "krajowe",
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

That is, a list of flat objects (CSV is not really useful unless you have a list of records, correct?), then something like this:

First, install the `csv` package from NPM:

```
npm install csv
```

Then, something like this:

```
const csv = require('csv');
const scraper = require('../scraper');
const desiredFields = [
  '_id'         ,
  'name'        ,
  'url'         ,
  'price'       ,
  'Stan'        ,
  'Przebieg'    ,
  'Pochodzenie' ,
  '__v'         ,
];

router.get('/:allegro', (req, res) => {
  scraper.process( req.param.allegro )
    .then( toCSV(desiredFields) )
    .then( responseBody => {
      res.send( responseBody );
      res.set( 'Content-Type', 'text/csv' );
    });
});
```

Where `toCSV()` is something like this using NPM's [`csv-writer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-writer):

```
const csv = require('csv-writer');

function toCSV( fields ) {
  const desiredFields = fields.map( field => ({
      id: field,
      title: field
    })
  );
  const writer = csv.createObjectCsvStringifier({
    header: desiredFields,
  });

  return list => {
    if (!listOfObjects || listofObjects.length < 1) {
      return ""
    }

    const header     = fields.map( field => ({ id: field, title: field }) );
    const writer     = csv.createObjectCsvStringifier( { header } );
    const headerLine = writer.getHeaderString();
    const dataLines  = writer.stringifyRecords(listObjects);

    return headerLine + dataLines;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change the content-type to something like `text/csv`, you could do so with:

```js
res.addHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv')
```

And instead using `res.json` to send the response, you'll need to change your JS objects to CSV data, you could do so using [object-to-csv](https://github.com/miscavage/object-to-csv) lib and then sending the data with `res.write`:

```js
const scraper = require('../scraper');
const ObjectToCSV = require('object-to-csv');

router.get('/:allegro', (req, res) => {
  scraper.process(req.param.allegro).then((list) => {
    res.addHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv');

    const instance = new ObjectToCSV({ data: list });

    res.write(instance.getCSV());
    res.end();
  });
});
```